# Adding elements to array from JSON is returning empty array. How can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a .JSON file, I've read the data and am using a `for...in` loop to loop through it.

If I use `console.log`, then I can print the data to the console, but if I try to add data to an array using the push function and `console.log` the array, I get an empty array.

Basically, how do I add the data to the array?

The code:

```js
let wordList = []

fetch("wordleanswers.json")
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        let myWord = data.toString()

        for (const singleData in data){
            wordList.push(singleData)
        }
    })

console.log(wordList)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Here is a .txt version of .json file (the text is just in an object in the .json): https://github.com/MissingFable/wordle_bot_4_python/blob/main/wordleanswers.TXT

Comment: Can you show us the json file?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async code to fetch the data. You need to await on the fetch before you log your array.

Try to use `then` at the end. Like below.

```js
let wordList = []

fetch("wordleanswers.json")
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        let myWord = data.toString()

        for (const singleData in data){
            wordList.push(singleData)
        }
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(wordList)
    })
```

Or you can put this whole code in async function and put `await` before fetch function call.

Edit: Adding the other solution (Using IIFE function)

```
(async () => {
  let wordList = []

  const response = await fetch("wordleanswers.json")
  const data = await response.json()
    

  for (const singleData in data){
     wordList.push(singleData)
  }

  console.log(wordList)

})()
```